# Trying to call a function_

Tags: python

I created the build_map function and I want to call the build_map function. I do not receive an error and the function is not indicating being called.

```
def build_map():
  list1 = ['a', 'b', 'd']
  list2 = [243, 452, (343, 3453)]
  list(zip(list1, list2))

build_map()
```

Comment: please read the error message, it tells you exactly what was wrong.

Comment: It's because the `build_map` needs two required parameters and you have not passed any at calling the function.

Comment: Please repeat [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the [intro tour]( https://stackoverflow.com/tour).  We expect you to consult existing resources -- see your tutorial on calling a function with parameters.  Stack Overflow is not intended to replace such research or to serve as an individual tutorial site.

Answer (score 4):

You are making new things inside the function, not using arguments provided by the caller, so remove the arguments from the definition of the function. If you want the function to do anything useful, make it `return` the resulting value:

```
def build_map():  # Arguments removed
  list1 = ['a', 'b', 'd']
  list2 = [243, 452, (343, 3453)]
  return list(zip(list1, list2))  # Result returned
```

Comment: def build_list():
  list1 = ['a', 'b', 'd']
  list2 = [243, 452, (343, 3453)]
  list(zip(list1, list2))    # nothing happens when I call the function

Comment: @MarkAmon: 1) You didn't add the `return` from my answer, so it's just returning `None`. 2) If you don't use the return value in some way, nothing will happen (unless you're in an interactive interpreter), the returned value will just be discarded. `print(build_map())` would display the return value.